# using comboBox with search parameters

Tags: c#

I made a question about an hour ago asking how to do something similar and after I got some help I was able to do it. Basically, I'm getting an error saying 
"Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'UltimateTeam.Toolkit.Parameter.Formation'"

Here's the code, searching for a player: I also get the error on the line that says Formation.

```
public async void start()
        {
                var searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
                var searchParameters = new PlayerSearchParameters
                {
Formation = comboBox2.SelectedItem == null ? Formation.FourThreeThree : (Formation)(comboBox2.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem2).Value2,
};
```

second piece of code:

```
foreach (Formation formation in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Formation)))
            {
                ComboboxItem2 item2 = new ComboboxItem2();
                item2.Text2 = formation.ToString();
                item2.Value2 = formation;
                comboBox2.Items.Add(item2);
            }
```

last piece of code:

```
public class ComboboxItem2
        {
            public string Text2 { get; set; }
            public object Value2 { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Text2;
            }
        }
```

Any ideas on how I could fix it?

Thanks,

Jack.

Comment: on which line you are getting the error

Comment: the one that says "Formation = comboBox2.SelectedItem == null ? Formation.FourThreeThree : (Formation)(comboBox2.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem2).Value2,"

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) to convert the `string` to your enum type `Formation`.

```
Formation = comboBox2.SelectedItem == null 
           ? Formation.FourThreeThree 
           : (Formation) Enum.Parse(typeof(Formation), comboBox2.Text);
```

**Edit** So `PlayerSearchParameters.Formation` is a `string`, the n this should work:

```
Formation = comboBox2.SelectedItem == null 
           ? Formation.FourThreeThree.ToString()
           : comboBox2.Text,
```

Comment: it needs to end with a ',' which I don't think I could do with that. It needs to end with a ',' because theirs more params you need to choose.

Comment: I just used that and got the same error, here's a screen cap: http://ttgstarify.info/i/a25eb02.png

Comment: @user2382644: What type is `PlayerSearchParameters.Formation`? I assumed that it's `Formation` but now i think that it's a string instead. Then you could either change that type to `Formation` or use the string representation like `comboBox2.Text` or `"FourThreeThree"`.

Comment: After trying it with another param it worked. I don't think it's an issue with the code. :(

Comment: It's a string I think. It's in a Library I added and it says that it's a const string.

Comment: @user2382644: Then just use the string. Edited my answer.

Comment: That doesn't make comboBox2 list all the Formations appear. There's about 20 different ones.